# Logical completeness of Hilbert system of axioms

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, euclidean-geometry, axioms

This is really a question about references. The [entry in Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0) about [Hilbert's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) states, in particular, that completeness of Hilbert's system was proven by Tarski in 1951. The reference is to the Russian encyclopedia of elementary mathematics, to which I don't have access, and I somehow am not able to find any references to this statement in the literature.

I have two questions:

1. The continuity axioms are not first-order-logic statements. What
   does then completeness mean in this situation?
2. Does anybody know a reference to the original proof by Tarski or any
   other proof of this statement, for that matter?

Comment: For 1, I'd say that Hilbert's *Foundations of Geometry* was a key step in the formalist vision of math, but his notion of completeness was vague, given that he was writing before the formalization of set theory and the standardization of first-order logic.

Comment: You should not trust Russian Wikipedia. It is written by uneducated people who accidentally seized power. Almost everything written there on mathematics contains a substantial amount of absurdity. Here is an example of a debate on what was written about the foundations of mathematics: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2/1

Comment: @Matt F. The question is though about the statement and the proof by Tarski, not Hilbert.

Comment: @Sergei Akbarov. I did not express any opinion about the content of any Wikipedia page.

Comment: The question currently mentions “the completeness of Hilbert’s system” and “not first-order” statements, as if asking about a statement by Hilbert and proof by Tarski. If you’re only interested in the Tarski part, it would help to clarify that.

Comment: @MattF. True. I was puzzled by  the Wikipedia entry literally saying that completeness of Hilbert's system was proven by Tarski. With the hindsight I would formulate the question differently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The original is Alfred Tarski's book "The completeness of elementary algebra and geometry", which was due to appear in 1940 but never made it into print because of the outbreak of WW2. An edition appeared after all in 1967 (Institut Blaise Pascal, Paris), but is not easy to come by.

Essentially the same argument is presented in Tarski's 1948/51 "A decision method for elementary algebra and geometry", available [here](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/reports/2008/R109.pdf).

Tarski uses an axiomatic setup of elementary geometry different (but equivalent) to Hilbert's, using only points (not lines or planes) as primitive terms, and two relation symbols, $B$ and $D$ (ternary and quaternary, respectively). $Bxyz$ signifies that the point $y$ is on the "line" $xz$ between the points $x$ and $z$ ("betweenness"), while $Dxyzw$ means that the distance between $x$ and $y$ equals that between $z$ and $w$ (the "equidistance" relation). Here, $x$, $y$, $z$ (and $w$) are allowed to coincide.

Full continuity is the second order axiom $\forall_{X}\forall_{Y}((\exists_{a}\forall_{x\in X}\forall_{y\in Y}Baxy)\rightarrow(\exists_{b}\forall_{x\in X}\forall_{y\in Y}Bxby))$, where $X$ and $Y$ are variables ranging over sets of points.

First order continuity is weaker, and is expressed as an axiom schema where $X$ and $Y$ are given as $\lbrace x\mid \phi(x)\rbrace$ and $\lbrace y\mid \psi(y)\rbrace$, respectively, for arbitrary first order formulas $\phi(x)=\phi(x,p_{1},\cdots,p_{n})$ and $\psi(y)=\psi(y,p_{1},\cdots,p_{n})$ that are allowed to contain parameters $p_{1},\cdots,p_{n}$.

A special case of first order continuity is the Circle Axiom, by which a line that contains an interior point of a circle (in the same plane) must meet that circle.

**Completeness** is the statement that any model $\mathfrak A$ of the axioms of elementary $n$-dimensional geometry without continuity is isomorphic to $K^{n}$ (with the obvious interpretations for the $B$ and $D$ relations) for a Pythagorean ordered field $K$ (that is $K\models\forall_{a}\forall_{b}\exists_{c}(a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2})$), uniquely determined by $\mathfrak A$ up to isomorphism.

Under full continuity, $K$ must be $\mathbb{R}$, under first order continuity $K$ must be real closed, and for the Circle Axiom $K$ merely needs to be Euclidean (i.e., $K\models\forall_{a}\exists_{b}(a=b^{2}\vee -a=b^{2})$).

This is the content of the **Representation Theorem**, Th. I, (16.15) in "Metamathematische Methoden in der Geometrie" by W. Schwabhäuser, W. Szmielew and A. Tarski, Springer Hochschultext, 1983, an excellent reference for the metamathematics of elementary geometry (in German).

**Edit:** Let me add a few comments.

1. The statement above that Tarki's setup is equivalent to Hilbert's is rather imprecise, as noted by Matt F. and others. Tarski works in first order logic, while a formalization of Hilbert's system is at least unclear. (Still, the axioms in Hilbert's axiom groups I-IV can be derived from Tarski's axioms, as shown in the Schwabhäuser, Szmielew, Tarski text).
2. For the same reason, it is not clear what it would mean for Hilbert's system to be complete (in the modern sense), and I do not claim that "completeness" of Hilbert's system follows from that of Tarski. Hilbert includes a "completeness axiom", to the effect that his "model" of the axioms in groups I-V (where V is archimedeanity) cannot be extended to a "model" with a larger universe.
3. To add to the confusion, my use of the word Completeness above (in the body of the answer, in reference to the Representation Theorem) was also unfortunate. Tarski has shown that the first order theory of real closed fields is complete (in the modern sense), and that, as a result, the same goes for the theory of $n$-dimensional elementary geometry (based on Tarski's axioms, with the first order continuity axiom schema included).

Comment: Why do you say that Tarski's setup is equivalent to Hilbert's? Tarski's is first-order and formalized, Hilbert's is not first-order and by 21st-century standards rather informal. I wouldn't say "different (but equivalent) to Hilbert's", when "based on Hilbert's ideas" seems more accurate.

Comment: @Matt F. Hilbert's axioms, as set forth in his *Grundlagen*, are, although informal, no less precise. Formalizations of his principles can be deduced in Tarski's system.

Comment: @MatthévanderLee How is your comment responsive to Matt's point that Hilbert's system is not first-order? The archimedean and completeness axioms in Hilbert's system fall outside Tarski's system (and so cannot be deduced therein).

Comment: @ToddTrimble I agree. Hilbert's archimedean and completeness axioms are not first order statements. Rather, they would be requirements on *models* of a first order formalization of geometry. So, as suggested by Matt, it would indeed be better to speak of Tarski's formalization as "based on Hilbert's system" rather than "equivalent to it".

Comment: Hilbert's completeness axiom ("the model cannot be extended") contradicts the upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem of first order model theory. (The second order axiom of full continuity ensures that $K=\mathbb{R}$, though.) And archimedeanity comes down to the field $K$ mentioned above being an Archimedean field.

Comment: After [agreeing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351908/logical-completeness-of-hilbert-system-of-axioms#comment882255_351936) that it shouldn't remain, your edit left the assertion that Tarski's system is "different (but equivalent) to Hilbert's".

Comment: I do not understand this discussion. Is it not possible to say that the Hilbert system is an extension by definitions of some axiomatic set theory, say, ZFC, and therefore can be considered as a first-order theory? The only vagueness, as far as I understand, lies in the meaning of the expression "equivalent first-order theories". Do people use this term?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov. Hilbert's system is not an "extension" of ZFC, whatever "extension" means. As we all know, there is a model in ZFC for the Hilbert's system. Hilbert's system is not first order, because two of the axioms, Archimedean and completeness use the wrong language (the range of quantification is wrong, in the first case it is natural numbers, which are not inherently present, in the second -- models)

Comment: @R.Matveev here is the meaning of the term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions I would say, Hilbert axioms can easily be presented as an extension by definition of ZFC (or NBG, MK, etc.). As, actually, everything in mathematics described in terms of set theory.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov. Any extension of ZFC or any other set theory capable of modelling $\mathbb{N}$ will be incomplete by Gödel's Theorem, while Tarski's system, which is based on  Hilbert's as explained above, is complete.

Comment: @R.Matveev this is another puzzle for me. If one theory is complete while another incomplete, then what is meant by "equivalence"? What are you arguing about?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov. Hilbert system is equivalent to Tarski, as explained above. This is somewhat informal, because Hilbert's system is slopy by modern standards and contains two statements which are not in the first order logic language. This is explained in the answer by Matthé van der Lee, above. By Tarski's theorem his and Hilberts systems are complete. ZFC is not complete and has nothing to do with this discussion.

Comment: @R.Matveev, if there is no definition (of equivalence) is this rigor in declarations apt?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov. I am not sure what your question/concern is. Let me summarize the answer/discussion. 1. Hilbert's system is not a formal system  in a modern sense of the word, consequently no mathematically/logically rigorous statement can be made about it.  2. Tarski devised another system of axioms based on (guided by, resembling, similar to, -- not a mathematical notion) Hilbert's. 3. Tarski proved that his system is complete. For more details, see the answer and the discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104085/discussion-between-r-matveev-and-sergei-akbarov).

Comment: I don't want to continue this discussion in chat. What you explain here, is clear without your explanations. What is not clear (and sounds strange) are declarations like this:
$$
\text{> Hilbert system is equivalent to Tarski, as explained above.}
$$ 
You should give a definition of this equivalence before writing this, @R.Matveev. And giving advices like this:
$$
\text{> For more details, see the answer and the discussion.}
$$